# How to modify behavior of syntax highlighting without editing the original source?

Tags: c, comment

There is a bug in C/C++ comment highlighting [(bug 11865)](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2013-06/msg00089.html)

Where the fix appears to be to modify the value of `c-font-lock-doc-comments`

Is there a way to do this in my emacs config, instead of having to keep a modified version of the original emacs source?

---

In the patch makes this change:

```
- (c-font-lock-doc-comments "/**$" limit gtkdoc-font-lock-doc-comments)
+ (c-font-lock-doc-comments "/**([^*/].*)?$" limit gtkdoc-font-lock-doc-comments)
```

Is there a way to apply this change locally?

Comment: While I didn't find an answer to this question, but managed to override the comment highlighting in this answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35001

Comment: The bug you linked to was for the *previous* public release of Emacs (in the year 2013), and should be fixed in the current stable release -- i.e., Emacs 25 should be fine, right?

Comment: @lawlist - it seems its spesific to gtkdoc style (which I don't use). So I should probably write a new report.