# Doxygen style for c-doc-comment-style?

Tags: c, comment

The option [c-doc-comment-style](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#Doc-Comments) supports javadoc, autodoc and gtkdoc.

Is there a way to get [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) support? (\returns, \note, \brief... etc)